# Pandas distinct count as a DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, count, distinct

Suppose I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df` with columns `a` and `b` and what I want is the number of distinct values of `b` per each `a`. I would do:

```
distcounts = df.groupby('a')['b'].nunique()
```

which gives the desidered result, but it is as Series object rather than another DataFrame. I'd like a DataFrame instead. In regular SQL, I'd do:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(DISTINCT(b)) FROM df
```

and haven't been able to emulate this query in Pandas exactly. How to?

Comment: You can call `reset_index()` on the result: `distcounts = df.groupby('a')['b'].nunique().reset_index()` or just convert to a df: `distcounts.to_frame()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
distcounts = df.groupby('a')['b'].nunique().reset_index()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,8,8],
                   'b':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   a  b
0  7  4
1  8  5
2  8  6

distcounts = df.groupby('a')['b'].nunique().reset_index()
print (distcounts)
   a  b
0  7  1
1  8  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative using [`Groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) instead:

```
df.groupby('a', as_index=False).agg({'b': 'nunique'})
```